# Http status code for updates with conditions

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Good morning:

I have a resource from my api that updates a record of my database if a condition is met, when it is met and the record is updated I return a HTTP status code 200, but I do not know what Http status code return when the condition is not met, since it can not be a 400 error, because the request is well formed

Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: I would return 200 and specify the result in the content of response.

Comment: Thank you for your response @PavelTřupek I use 200 code and send message to client in body response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 4xx even if the request is well-formed (what makes you think otherwise?):

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
>   seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
>   error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.
>   These status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents
>   SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

(see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.4xx)

Returning a 2xx when the request failed doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I thought about using the code 400, but I read that this code was used for malformed requests or syntax errors, not for the application's own conditions